# What is yumdownloader default target folder?

Tags: yum

Where does `yumdownloader` put the files it downloads by default ? I did

```
yumdownloader --resolve xirg-x11-drv-nvidia
yumdownloader --source nvidia-kmod
```

But now I order to run an rpmbuild I need to know the complete name of the `nvidia-kmod` it downloader if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the current dir. Manpage:

```
NAME
       yumdownloader

SYNOPSIS
       yumdownloader [options] package1 [package2...]

DESCRIPTION
       yumdownloader is a program for downloading RPMs from Yum repositories.

GENERAL OPTIONS
       --destdir DIR
              Specify a destination directory for the download. Defaults to the current directory.
```

If you want to change this behavior, use `--destdir`.